# What's the real different between "FileWriter.write" and "FileWriter.append"?

Tags: java, filewriter

Here is code.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class start {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String content = "Yes, ";
        String path = "something.txt";
        FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, true);
        fWriter.write(content);
        //It's get same result if use "fWriter.append(content)"
        fWriter.close();
    }
}
```

I found actually it's the third parameter of FileWriter constructor (true or false) to determine overwrite or append.

If use true, then it always append no matter use write or append method.

If use false, it always overwrite.

So, what's real different between write and append method?

Comment: See the [doc for the append method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#append-java.lang.CharSequence-): "An invocation of this method of the form `out.append(csq)` behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation `out.write(csq.toString())`"

Comment: There is no difference. The reason `append` is there is to allow `Writer` to implement the `Appendable` interface.

Comment: as the documentation said: write will only take a String which must not be null and returns void AND append will take any CharSequence which can be null and return the Writer so it can be chained.